# EventListener not always being loaded

Tags: javascript, html

I have three 'click' event listeners coded in my javascript. The first two always work (for the elements with id's `cs-detail-toggle` and `tc-detail-toggle`) but the last one (for the element with id cc-detail-toggle) only works sometimes.

Sometimes when I load the site in my browser I can see the event listener in dev tools, other times it is not there.

The purpose of all three event listeners is the same - change the CSS display property of respective div's between `'none'` and `'block'`.

```js
/** CSS Cheat Sheet Detail Toggle */
const csToggle = document.getElementById('cs-detail-toggle')
const csDetail = document.getElementById('cs-details')

function toggleCsDisplay() {
    if (csDetail.style.display === 'none') {
        csDetail.style.display = 'block'
    } else {
        csDetail.style.display = 'none'
    }
}
csToggle.addEventListener('click', toggleCsDisplay);


/** Tea Cozy Detail Toggle **/
const tcToggle = document.getElementById('tc-detail-toggle')
const tcDetail = document.getElementById('tc-details')

function toggleTcDisplay() {
    if (tcDetail.style.display === 'none') {
        tcDetail.style.display = 'block'
    } else {
        tcDetail.style.display = 'none'
    }
}

tcToggle.addEventListener('click', toggleTcDisplay);


/** Credit Card Checker Detail Toggle **/

const ccToggle = document.getElementById('cc-detail-toggle')
const ccDetail = document.getElementById('cc-details')

function toggleCcDisplay() {
    if (ccDetail.style.display === 'none') {
        ccDetail.style.display = 'block'
    } else {
        ccDetail.style.display = 'none'
    }
}

ccToggle.addEventListener('click', toggleCcDisplay);
```

```html
<section class="projects">
  <h2>Projects</h2>
  <div class="projects-container">
    <div class="project-card">
      <h3>CSS Positioning Cheat Sheet</h3>
      <img
        src="./assets/css-cheat-sq.png"
        alt="screenshot preview of css positioning cheat sheet project"
      />
      <p id="cs-detail-toggle">+ Details and Links</p>
      <div id="cs-details" class="details">
        <p>Quick reference guide for the 5 main CSS positioning types</p>
        <p>Made as part of Codecademy Web Development Foundations Course</p>
        <p>Tech used - HTML 5 and CSS3</p>
        <a href="https://github.com/YSquid/positioning-cheat-sheet" target="_blank"><i class="fa-brands fa-github"></i
          >GitHub Repository</a>
        <a href="https://codepen.io/ysquid/pen/NWMXxwp" target="_blank"><i class="fa-brands fa-codepen"></i>View in CodePen</a>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="project-card">
      <h3>Tea Cozy Landing Page</h3>
      <img src="./assets/tea-cozy-sq.png" alt="screenshot preview of tea cozt landing page project">
      <p id="tc-detail-toggle">+ Details and Links</p>
      <div id="tc-details" class="details">
        <p>Landing page for a ficitonal business</p>
        <p>Created according to provided website spec</p>
        <p>Made as part of Codecademy Web Development Foundations Course</p>
        <p>Tech used - HTML5 and CSS3</p>
        <a href="https://github.com/YSquid/tea-cozy" target="_blank"><i class='fa-brands fa-github'></i>GitHub Repository</a>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="project-card">
      <h3>Credit Card Number Validator</h3>
      <img src="./assets/card-checker-sq.png" alt="image of credit card with number highlighted and first step of luhn alorithm shown">
      <p id="cc-detail-toggle">+ Details and Links</p>
      <div id="cc-details" class="details">
        <p>Program for checking credit cards</p>
        <p>Can accept array of credit card numbers, and find the invalid ones</p>
        <p>Takes list of invalid cards, and prints array of the credit card companies whose cards are in the invalid array</p>
        <p>Tech used - Javascript, NodeJS for testing</p>
        <a href="https://github.com/YSquid/credit-card-checker" target="_blank"><i class='fa-brands fa-github'></i>GitHub Repository</a>
        <a href="https://codepen.io/ysquid/pen/gOzxWNN" target="_blank"><i class="fa-brands fa-codepen"></i>View in CodePen</a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

Comment: In the runnable code snippet, when you debug, can you indicate specifically what operation isn't producing the result you expect?

Comment: Only way event is not going to be there is if the element is removed and added back OR you had an error and the event was not added which you would see in the dev tools.

Comment: @david The interesting thing is that in the runnable code snippet, the listener works as expected. It's only an issue when I open in the browser.

Comment: @epascarello I am now seeing the issue in my dev tools. Error reads as follows:

index.js:44 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'addEventListener')

So something wtih my registration of the event listener in JS is wrong? Or something about the variable I saved to access my element is wrong perhaps?

Comment: @YSquid: Then you may need to take some time to produce a [mcve] which demonstrates the problem.

Answer (score 0):

After some help debugging from the comments I was able to find a solution, posting for future reference.

As I had my script tag in the HTML `head` with the  `async` attribute, the javascript file was loading before the DOM element existed.

Here was my script tag placement before.

```
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
    <title></title>
    <meta name="description" content="" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./index.css" />
    <script
      src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/620d1d46ff.js"
      crossorigin="anonymous"
    ></script>
    <!--font awesome import-->

    <!--SCRIPT PLACEMENT NOT WORKING -->
    <script src="./index.js" async></script>
  </head>
```

I moved my script tag to the bottom of my code just before the closing body tag, and it all works now.

Here is the working HTML (scroll the bottom to find the script tag, comment there to flag it).

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
    <title></title>
    <meta name="description" content="" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./index.css" />
    <script
      src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/620d1d46ff.js"
      crossorigin="anonymous"
    ></script>
    <!--font awesome import-->
  </head>
  <body>
    <nav>
      <div class="nav-left">
      <h1>Ahmad Kariem</h1>
      <a href="https://github.com/YSquid" target="_blank"
        ><i class="fa-brands fa-github"></i
      ></a>
      <a href="https://www.linkedin.com/in/ahmad-kariem/" target="_blank"
        ><i class="fa-brands fa-linkedin"></i
      ></a>
    </div>
    <div class="nav-right">
      <ul>
        <li>About</li>
        <li>Education</li>
        <li>Projects</li>
        <li>Skills</li>
        <li>Contact</li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    </nav>

    <main>
      <section class="about">
        <h2 class="about-title">About Me</h2>
        <div class="about-container">
          <div class="about-text">
            <p>
              Hi! My name is Ahmad Kariem, and I am a full stack developer from
              Saskatoon Sasktchewan.
            </p>
            <p>
              My educational background is in biochemistry and business, and I
              have worked in a number of roles in my career including
              tech-sales, digitial marketing, and data analysis. In early 2022,
              I began my journey to becoming a self-taught full-stack software
              developer. I have been studying using tools such as Codecademy and
              Freecodecamp to learn skills in HTML, CSS, Javascript, ReactJS and
              more!
            </p>
            <p>
              In my spare time I like to play video games, golf, watch football
              and e-sports, run, and lift weights.
            </p>
          </div>
          <img
            src="./assets/portfoli site pic.jpg"
            alt="A headshot of Ahmad in a suit"
          />
        </div>
      </section>

      <section class="education">
        <h2>Education</h2>
        <div class="education-container">
          <div class="edu-card">
            <h3>B.Sc Biochemistry - 2015</h3>
            <ul>
              <li>Univeristy of Saskatchewan</li>
              <li>Graduated with High Honors</li>
            </ul>
          </div>
          <div class="edu-card">
            <h3>Masters in Business Administration (MBA) - 2019</h3>
            <ul>
              <li>University of Saskatchewan</li>
              <li>Graduated with Honors</li>
            </ul>
          </div>
          <div class="edu-card">
            <h3>Full-Stack Softwar Engineer - In Progress</h3>
            <ul>
              <li>Codecademy</li>
              <li>Started September 2022</li>
            </ul>
          </div>
        </div>
      </section>

      <section class="projects">
        <h2>Projects</h2>
        <div class="projects-container">
          <div class="project-card">
            <h3>CSS Positioning Cheat Sheet</h3>
            <img
              src="./assets/css-cheat-sq.png"
              alt="screenshot preview of css positioning cheat sheet project"
            />
            <button id="cs-detail-toggle">+ Details and Links</button>
            <div id="cs-details" class="details">
              <p>Quick reference guide for the 5 main CSS positioning types</p>
              <p>Made as part of Codecademy Web Development Foundations Course</p>
              <p>Tech used - HTML 5 and CSS3</p>
              <a href="https://github.com/YSquid/positioning-cheat-sheet" target="_blank"><i class="fa-brands fa-github"></i
                >GitHub Repository</a>
              <a href="https://codepen.io/ysquid/pen/NWMXxwp" target="_blank"><i class="fa-brands fa-codepen"></i>View in CodePen</a>
            </div>
          </div>

          <div class="project-card">
            <h3>Tea Cozy Landing Page</h3>
            <img src="./assets/tea-cozy-sq.png" alt="screenshot preview of tea cozt landing page project">
            <button id="tc-detail-toggle">+ Details and Links</button>
            <div id="tc-details" class="details">
              <p>Landing page for a ficitonal business</p>
              <p>Created according to provided website spec</p>
              <p>Made as part of Codecademy Web Development Foundations Course</p>
              <p>Tech used - HTML5 and CSS3</p>
              <a href="https://github.com/YSquid/tea-cozy" target="_blank"><i class='fa-brands fa-github'></i>GitHub Repository</a>
            </div>
          </div>

          <div class="project-card">
            <h3>Credit Card Number Validator</h3>
            <img src="./assets/card-checker-sq.png" alt="image of credit card with number highlighted and first step of luhn alorithm shown">
            <button id="cc-detail-toggle">+ Details and Links</button>
            <div id="cc-details" class="details">
              <p>Program for checking credit cards</p>
              <p>Can accept array of credit card numbers, and find the invalid ones</p>
              <p>Takes list of invalid cards, and prints array of the credit card companies whose cards are in the invalid array</p>
              <p>Tech used - Javascript, NodeJS for testing</p>
              <a href="https://github.com/YSquid/credit-card-checker" target="_blank"><i class='fa-brands fa-github'></i>GitHub Repository</a>
              <a href="https://codepen.io/ysquid/pen/gOzxWNN" target="_blank"><i class="fa-brands fa-codepen"></i>View in CodePen</a>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </section>

      <section class="skills">
        <h2>Skills</h2>
        <div class="skills-container">
          <i class="fa-brands fa-html5"></i>
          <i class="fa-brands fa-css3-alt"></i>
          <i class="fa-brands fa-square-js"></i>
          <i class="fa-brands fa-react"></i>
          <i class="fa-brands fa-node"></i>
          <i class="fa-brands fa-npm"></i>
          <i class="fa-brands fa-git"></i>
          <i class="fa-brands fa-github"></i>
          <i class="fa-brands fa-chrome"></i>
          <i class="fa-solid fa-terminal"></i>
        </div>
      </section>

      <section class="contact">
        <h2>Please feel free to reach out and connect!</h2>
        <div class="contact-container">
          <a href="mailto:ahk648@gmail.com" target="_blank"><i class="fa-solid fa-envelope"></i></a>
          <a href="https://www.linkedin.com/in/ahmad-kariem/"><i class="fa-brands fa-linkedin"></i></a>
          <a href="https://github.com/YSquid"><i class="fa-brands fa-github"></i></a>
        </div>
      </section>
    </main>
    <!--SCRIPT PLACEMENT WORKING -->
    <script src="./index.js" async></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Thanks to the commenters for putting me on the path to finding the solution!